# Angular 2 page not refreshed on router.navigate

Tags: angular

When I route to a new page on click of a button, the data of an ngx datatable which is on that page doesn't get refreshed; it only gets refreshed once the I reload/ refresh the page. Any idea where I might be going wrong here?

Necessary files :

solution-list.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 pageTitle">Solutions</div>
    <div [hidden]="!busy" class="col-sm-3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-spin" style="float:right;"></span></div>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="createNewButtonClicked()" id="createButton">Create New</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"(click)="retrieveArchivedButtonClicked()" id="retrieveArchivedButton">Retrieve Archived</button>
    <label *ngIf="isAdmin" style="padding-right:2px;">Show All:</label><input *ngIf="isAdmin" type="checkbox" [checked]="showAll" (change)="toggleShowAll()" />
</div>

<ngx-datatable #table
               class='datatable'
               [sortType]="'single'"
               [columns]="columns"
               [columnMode]="'flex'"
               [headerHeight]="40"
               [footerHeight]="50"
               [rowHeight]="'auto'"
               [limit]="10"
               [rows]='rows'>

    <template #sortableColumnTemplate let-sort="sortFn" let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template>
        <span (click)="sort()" class="sort-fullwidth">{{column?.name}}</span>
        <input class="filter-box" placeholder='' (keyup)='updateFilter($event)' />
    </template>

    <template #actionRowTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <div style="display:block; text-align:center;">
            <a title="copy" (click)="copySolution(row)"><i class="button-icon button-icon-copy"></i></a>
            <!--<a (click)="copySolution(row)">Copy</a>-->
            <!-- | -->
            <!--<a (click)="showDeleteConfirmation(row)">Delete</a>-->
            <a title="history" (click)="showHistory(row)"><i class="button-icon button-icon-history"></i></a>
            <a title="delete" (click)="showDeleteConfirmation(row)" id="delete-{{row.$$index}}"><i class="button-icon button-icon-delete"></i></a>

            <!--|
            <a (click)="showHistory(row)">History</a>-->
        </div>
    </template>

    <template #customColumnTemplate let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <div style="display:block; text-align:left;">
            <a (click)="navigateToEdit(row)">{{row.name}}</a>
        </div>
    </template>
</ngx-datatable>

<!--<modal #historyModal>
    <div class="app-modal-header">
        <strong>History for {{solutionHistoryName}}</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
        <solution-history [solutionHistories]="solutionHistories"></solution-history>
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="historyModal.hide()">Close</button>
    </div>
</modal>-->

<modal #deleteModal>
    <div class="app-modal-header" style="border:none;">
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-body">
        Confirm deletion of <span style="font-weight:bold;">{{solutionToDelete?.name}}</span> and it's associated project.
    </div>
    <div class="app-modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="deleteModal.hide()" id="cancelDeleteButton">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteSolution()" id="confirmDeleteButton">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</modal>
```

solution-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { SolutionMetadata, SolutionHistory } from '../../models/solution.models';

import { SolutionHistoryComponent } from './subcomponents/solution-history.component';
import { GridComponent } from '../../components/shared/util/grid.component';
import { ModalComponent } from '../../components/shared/util/modal.component';
import { UserRoleService } from "../../services/userRole.service";
import { SolutionManagementService } from '../../services/solutionManagement.service';
import { SolutionService } from '../../services/solution.service';
import { ToasterNotificationService } from '../../services/toasternotification.service';
import { AuthHttp } from 'ng2-adal/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'solution-list',
    templateUrl: './solution-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../shared/util/grid.component.css',
        '../shared/util/form-sharedstyle.css',
        './solution-list.component.css']
})
export class SolutionListComponent extends GridComponent {
    solutions: SolutionMetadata[];
    isAdmin: boolean = false;
    showAll: boolean = false;
    busy: boolean = false;
    userName: string;
    solutionHistories: SolutionHistory[];
    solutionToDelete: SolutionMetadata;
    solutionHistoryName: string;

    @ViewChild('deleteModal') deleteModal: ModalComponent;

    constructor(private _solutionService: SolutionService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _solutionManagementService: SolutionManagementService,
        private _userRoleService: UserRoleService,
        private toasterService: ToasterNotificationService,
        authHttp: AuthHttp) {
        super(false, authHttp);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit();
        this.initDataTable();
        this._solutionManagementService.ClearAll();

        this._solutionService.Solutions.subscribe(data => {
            this.busy = false;
            this.solutions = data;
            this.updateRows(this.showAll ? data : data.filter(it => it.owner == this.userName || it.authorizedUsers.indexOf(this.userName) >= 0));
        });

        this.userName = this._userRoleService.getUserName();
        this.isAdmin = this._userRoleService.isInRole(this._userRoleService.roles.AdminRole);
        //this.isAdmin = true;

        if (this.isAdmin) {
            this._solutionService.getAllSolutionSummaries().subscribe(
                () => { }, // handled in Solutions subscription callback
                (error: any) => {
                    this.toasterService.Notify("Error", "An error occured while retrieving the solutions.");
                    this.table.messages.emptyMessage = "No records."
                });
        }
        else {
            this._solutionService.getSolutionSummaries().subscribe(
                () => { }, // handled in Solutions subscription callback
                (error: any) => {
                    this.toasterService.Notify("Error", "An error occured while retrieving the solutions.");
                    this.table.messages.emptyMessage = "No records."
                });
        }
    }

    copySolution(solution: SolutionMetadata) {
        this.busy = true;
        this._solutionService.copySolution(solution.id).subscribe(
            () => { }, // handled in Solutions subscription callback
            (error: any) => {
                this.busy = false;
                this.toasterService.Notify("error", "An error occured while copying solution " + solution.name);
            });
    }

    navigateToEdit(solutionSummary: SolutionMetadata) {
        this._router.navigate(['solutions/edit', solutionSummary.id]);
    }

    //RTH - Will need to be renamed properly later. Show history in V7 is its own view.
    showHistory(solutionSummary: SolutionMetadata) {
        this._router.navigate(['solutions/history/' + solutionSummary.id]);
    }

    showDeleteConfirmation(solutionSummary: SolutionMetadata) {
        this.solutionToDelete = solutionSummary;
        this.deleteModal.show();
    }


    deleteSolution() {
        if (this.solutionToDelete)
        {
            this.busy = true;
            this.deleteModal.hide();
            this._solutionService.deleteSolution(this.solutionToDelete.id).subscribe(
                () => { },
                (error: any) => {
                    this.busy = false;
                    this.toasterService.Notify("error", "An error occured while deleting the solution.");
                });
        }
    }

    toggleShowAll()
    {
        this.showAll = !this.showAll;
        if (this.showAll && this.solutions) {
            this.updateRows(this.solutions);
        }
        else if (this.solutions)
        {
            this.updateRows(this.solutions.filter(it => it.owner == this.userName || it.authorizedUsers.indexOf(this.userName) >= 0));
        }
    }

    initDataTable() {

        this.columns = [
            {
                name: 'Solution Name',
                prop: 'name',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 2,
                cellTemplate: this.customColumnTemplate,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate
            },
            {
                name: 'Description',
                prop: 'description',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 3,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate
            },
            {
                name: 'Solution Owner',
                prop: 'owner',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 2,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate
            },
            {
                name: '# RGs',
                prop: 'resourceGroupCount',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: .7,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate
            },
            {
                name: 'Version',
                prop: 'version',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 1,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate
            },
            {
                name: 'Action',
                cellTemplate: this.actionRowTemplate,
                sortable: false,
                flexGrow: 2
            }
        ];
    }

    createNewButtonClicked() {
        this._router.navigate(['/solutions/create']);
    }

    retrieveArchivedButtonClicked() {
        this._router.navigate(['/solutions/retrievearchived']);
    }



}
```

solution.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { Solution, SolutionMetadata, SolutionHistory, SolutionComparison, Landscape } from '../models/solution.models';
import { LandscapeDetail } from '../components/designer/models/landscape-detail.models';
import { AuthHttp } from 'ng2-adal/core';

@Injectable()
export class SolutionService
{
    private _solutions: SolutionMetadata[];
    public Solutions: Subject<SolutionMetadata[]>;

    constructor(private _http: AuthHttp) {
        this.Solutions = new Subject<SolutionMetadata[]>();
    }

    getSolutionSummaries(): Observable<SolutionMetadata[]>
    {
        if (this._solutions)
        {
            this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
            return Observable.of(this._solutions);
        }
        else {
            return this._http.get('api/solutions')
                .map(response => response.json() as SolutionMetadata[])
                .do(solutions => {
                    this._solutions = solutions;
                    this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
                    return solutions;
                });
        }

    }

    getAllSolutionSummaries(): Observable<SolutionMetadata[]>
    {
        if (this._solutions) {
            this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
            return Observable.of(this._solutions);
        }
        else {
            return this._http.get('api/solutions/all')
                .map(response => response.json() as SolutionMetadata[])
                .do(solutions => {
                    this._solutions = solutions;
                    this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
                    return solutions;
                });
        }

    }

    getSolution(id: string): Observable<Solution>
    {
        return this._http.get('api/solutions/details/' + id)
            .map(response => response.json() as Solution);
    }

    createSolution(solution: Solution): Observable<Solution>
    {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        return this._http.post('api/solutions/create', JSON.stringify(solution), options)
            .map(response => response.json() as Solution)
            .do(solution => {
                let metadata = this.createMetadataFromSolution(solution);

                if (!this._solutions) {
                    this._solutions = [];
                }
                this._solutions.unshift(metadata);
                this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
                return solution;
            });
    }

    editSolution(solution: any): Observable<SolutionMetadata>
    {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        return this._http.post('api/solutions/edit', JSON.stringify(solution), options)
            .map(response => response.json() as SolutionMetadata)
            .do(metadata => {
                let index = this._solutions.findIndex(it => it.id == solution.id);
                this._solutions[index] = metadata;
                this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
                return metadata;
            });
    }

    copySolution(id: string): Observable<any>
    {
        return this._http.get('api/solutions/copy/' + id)
            .map(response => response.json() as SolutionMetadata)
            .do(metadata => {
                this._solutions.unshift(metadata);
                this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
            });
    }

    //Checks if solution needs to be converted from CloudShaper and/or returns solution.
    getOrConvertSolution(id: string): Observable<Solution> {
        return this._http.get('api/solutions/getOrConvert/' + id)
            .map(response => response.json() as Solution);
    }

    getHistories(id: string): Observable<SolutionHistory[]> {
        return this._http.get('api/solutions/histories/' + id)
            .map(response => response.json() as SolutionHistory[]);
    }

    getComparison(archiveId: string, solutionId: string): Observable<SolutionComparison> {
        let parameters = '?archiveId=' + archiveId + '&solutionId=' + solutionId;
        return this._http.get('api/solutions/compare' + parameters)
            .map(response => response.json() as SolutionComparison)
    }

    deleteSolution(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.delete('api/solutions/' + id)
            .do(data => {
                let index = this._solutions.findIndex(it => it.id == id);
                this._solutions.splice(index, 1);
                this.Solutions.next(this._solutions);
            });
    }

    deleteSolutionFromProjectsList(id: string): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.delete('api/solutions/' + id);
    }

    deleteLandscape(solutionId: string, landscapeName: string): Observable<any> {
        let url = "api/solutions/landscape?solutionId=" + solutionId + "&landscapeName=" + landscapeName;
        return this._http.delete(url);
    }

    saveLandscapeDetail(solutionId: string, landscapeDetails: LandscapeDetail): Observable<Solution> {
        let url: string = 'api/solutions/saveLandscapeDetail/' + solutionId;
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(landscapeDetails), options)
            .map(response => response.json() as Solution);
    }

    saveLandscape(solutionId: string, landscape: Landscape): Observable<any> {
        let url: string = 'api/solutions/landscape?solutionId=' + solutionId;

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });

        return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(landscape), options)
            .map(response => response._body as string);
    }

    copyLandscape(solutionId: string, sourceLandscapeName: string, targetLandscapeName: string): Observable<any> {
        let url: string = 'api/solutions/landscape/copy?solutionId=' + solutionId
                        + '&sourceLandscapeName=' + sourceLandscapeName
                        + '&targetLandscapeName=' + targetLandscapeName;

        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() as Landscape);
    }

    isUniqueName(solutionName: string): Observable<boolean>
    {
        let url: string = 'api/solutions/isUniqueName?name=' + solutionName;

        return this._http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() as boolean)
    }

    private createMetadataFromSolution(solution: Solution): SolutionMetadata
    {
        return <SolutionMetadata>{
            id: solution.id,
            name: solution.name,
            description: solution.description,
            resourceGroupCount: 0,
            owner: solution.createdBy,
            version: solution.version,
            useTags: solution.taggingEnabled,
            createdOn: solution.createdOn,
            createdBy: solution.createdBy,
            editedBy: solution.editedBy,
            editedOn: solution.editedOn,
            cloudserviceType: solution.landscapeDetail.cloudServiceProvider
        };
    }
}
```

archived-solution-list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { SolutionMetadata, SolutionHistory } from '../../models/solution.models';

import { SolutionHistoryComponent } from './subcomponents/solution-history.component';
import { ArcGridComponent } from '../../components/shared/util/arc-grid.component';
import { GridComponent } from '../../components/shared/util/grid.component';
import { ModalComponent } from '../../components/shared/util/modal.component';
import { UserRoleService } from "../../services/userRole.service";
import { SolutionManagementService } from '../../services/solutionManagement.service';
import { ArchivedSolutionService } from '../../services/archivedSolution.service';
//import { SolutionService } from '../../services/solution.service';
import { ToasterNotificationService } from '../../services/toasternotification.service';
import { AuthHttp } from 'ng2-adal/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'archived-solution-list',
    templateUrl: './archived-solution-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../shared/util/arc-grid.component.css',
        '../shared/util/form-sharedstyle.css',
        './archived-solution-list.component.css']
})
export class ArchivedSolutionListComponent extends ArcGridComponent {
    solutions: SolutionMetadata[];
    isAdmin: boolean = false;
    showAll: boolean = false;
    busy: boolean = false;
    userName: string;
    solutionHistories: SolutionHistory[];
    solutionToDelete: SolutionMetadata;
    solutionHistoryName: string;
    isRetrieveArchivedClicked: boolean = false;


    @ViewChild('archivedSolutionsModal') archivedSolutionsModal: ModalComponent;

    constructor(private _archivedSolutionService: ArchivedSolutionService,
        private _router: Router,
        private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private _solutionManagementService: SolutionManagementService,
        private _userRoleService: UserRoleService,
        private toasterService: ToasterNotificationService,
        authHttp: AuthHttp) {
        super(false, authHttp);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        super.ngOnInit();
        this.initArcDataTable();
        this._solutionManagementService.ClearAll();

        this._archivedSolutionService.Solutions.subscribe(data => {
            this.busy = false;
            this.solutions = data;
            this.updateRows2(this.showAll ? data : data.filter(it => it.owner == this.userName || it.authorizedUsers.indexOf(this.userName) >= 0));
        });

        this.userName = this._userRoleService.getUserName();
        //this.isAdmin = true;
        this.isAdmin = this._userRoleService.isInRole(this._userRoleService.roles.AdminRole);

        if (this.isAdmin) {
            this._archivedSolutionService.getAllArchivedSolutionSummaries().subscribe(
                () => { }, // handled in Solutions subscription callback
                (error: any) => {
                    this.toasterService.Notify("Error", "An error occured while retrieving the archived solutions.");
                    this.table2.messages.emptyMessage = "No records."
                });
        }
        else {
            this._archivedSolutionService.getArchivedSolutionSummaries().subscribe(
                () => { }, // handled in Solutions subscription callback
                (error: any) => {
                    this.toasterService.Notify("Error", "An error occured while retrieving the archived solutions.");
                    this.table2.messages.emptyMessage = "No records."
                });
        }
    }

    restoreSolution() {
        console.log("Restore Solution clicked!");
    }


    toggleShowAll() {
        this.showAll = !this.showAll;
        if (this.showAll && this.solutions) {
            this.updateRows2(this.solutions);
        }
        else if (this.solutions) {
            this.updateRows2(this.solutions.filter(it => it.owner == this.userName || it.authorizedUsers.indexOf(this.userName) >= 0));
        }
    }


    initArcDataTable() {
        this.columns2 = [
            {
                name: 'Solution',
                prop: 'name',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 2,
                cellTemplate: this.customColumnTemplate2,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate2
            },
            {
                name: 'Description',
                prop: 'description',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 3,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate2
            },
            {
                name: 'Solution Owner',
                prop: 'owner',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 2,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate2
            },
            {
                name: '# RGs',
                prop: 'resourceGroupCount',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: .7,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate2
            },
            {
                name: 'Version',
                prop: 'version',
                sortable: true,
                sortString: '',
                flexGrow: 1,
                headerTemplate: this.sortableColumnTemplate2
            },
            {
                name: 'Action',
                cellTemplate: this.actionRowTemplate2,
                sortable: false,
                flexGrow: 2
            }
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: refresh means? **angular wont refresh the pages**

Comment: actually there is an ngx datatable in the new page..that table's data is not getting refreshed

Comment: An error is probably blocking the rendering of the page. Have you checked the console in the browser?